# Split multiple values into two or more arrays

Tags: php, arrays, split

For example I have this values => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

I want to get results something like this,
`1,2,3,4`
`5,6,7,8`

I tried using array_chunk would be like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 8
        )

)
```

I do not know how to split or merge [0][1][2][3] into one array [0] => 1,2,3,4 and [1] => 5,6,7,8

I need your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You just did it with `array_chunk()` didn't you?

Comment: what do you mean you have values =>1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8? how do you `have` them? are they all inside one array? how are they stored?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, but do not know how to implode after using array_chunk

Comment: @Webeng They are just example. I will get them after submit form. I am creating add rows to table, so I need to get the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `implode` after you use `array_chunk`.

```
$chunked = array_chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 4);

foreach($chunked as $chunk) {
     $imploded[] = implode(',', $chunk);
}

print_r($imploded); // Array ( [0] => 1,2,3,4 [1] => 5,6,7,8 )
```

Comment: Simply codes while I need several hours *face palm*. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You can walk the resulting chunks and apply the implode function

```
$values = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

$newValues = array_chunk($values, 4);

array_walk(
  $newValues,
  function(&$chunk)
  {
    $chunk = implode(',', $chunk);
  }
);

print_r($newValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

After calling `array_chunk` you can use `array_map` to implode each sub-array.

```
$result = array_map(function($subarray) {
    return implode(',', $subarray);
}, $chunked_array);
```